# what is the real electrons flow of a current source diagram

Tags: transistors, power, current, resistors

[image]

what is the real electrons flow when a current source symbol drawn
.In arrow way or other way

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a very basic question that is easily serviced by googling and there's no attempt to try and figure this out from the OP.

Comment: You should read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current and carefully read what it says in the section "Conventions".

Comment: pity about the colour scheme that simulator uses, green for +ve, red for -ve, which is the opposite of how most instruments colour their terminals

Answer (score 4):

Electrical engineers deal with conventional current and, in general, don't worry about electron flow. Not all current is due to the flow of electrons. In many situations positive ions can flow too.

Current flows from the power source + to -. You have posted a static picture of some simulation with a current source so I have no idea which direction the dots will move. I would expect that the arrow in the 10 mA current source indicates the conventional current direction and that the dots should run clockwise around the circuit.

Comment: Current flows in loops. If it flows from + to - in one part of the circuit it must flow from - to + in another part of the circuit.

Comment: @ThePhoton, spot the edit.